# function getBrowserType () Why is Chrome showing as Mozilla?

Tags: php, google-chrome, mozilla

I have also added Chrome but removed it right now because it had no effect at all.
In MySQL where the information is stored it shows mozilla for Mozilla and for Chrome. Why? Does Chrome have his own code?

```
function getBrowserType () {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    {
       $HTTP_USER_AGENT = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    }
    else if (!empty($HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    {
       $HTTP_USER_AGENT = $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    }
    else if (!isset($HTTP_USER_AGENT))
    {
       $HTTP_USER_AGENT = '';
    }
    if (preg_match('/Opera(\/| )([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})/', $HTTP_USER_AGENT, $log_version))
    {
       $browser_version = $log_version[2];
       $browser_agent = 'opera';
    }
    else if (preg_match('/MSIE ([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})/', $HTTP_USER_AGENT, $log_version))
    {
       $browser_version = $log_version[1];
       $browser_agent = 'ie';
    }
    else if (preg_match('/OmniWeb\/([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})/', $HTTP_USER_AGENT, $log_version))
    {
       $browser_version = $log_version[1];
       $browser_agent = 'omniweb';
    }
    else if (preg_match('/Netscape([0-9]{1})/', $HTTP_USER_AGENT, $log_version))
    {
       $browser_version = $log_version[1];
       $browser_agent = 'netscape';
    }
    else if (preg_match('/Mozilla\/([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})/', $HTTP_USER_AGENT, $log_version))
    {
       $browser_version = $log_version[1];
       $browser_agent = 'mozilla';
    }
    else if (preg_match('/Konqueror\/([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})/', $HTTP_USER_AGENT, $log_version))
    {
       $browser_version = $log_version[1];
       $browser_agent = 'konqueror';
    }
    else
    {
       $browser_version = 0;
       $browser_agent = 'other';
    }
    return $browser_agent;
    }
```

Comment: Chrome gives string like `"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11"` So it matches `'/Mozilla\/([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})/'`

Comment: http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php
This code I found here works great, tested it.

```
<?php
function getBrowser() 
{ 
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $platform = 'Unknown';
    $version= "";

    //First get the platform?
    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'windows';
    }

    // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer'; 
        $ub = "MSIE"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox'; 
        $ub = "Firefox"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Google Chrome'; 
        $ub = "Chrome"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Apple Safari'; 
        $ub = "Safari"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Opera'; 
        $ub = "Opera"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Netscape'; 
        $ub = "Netscape"; 
    } 

    // finally get the correct version number
    $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
    $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
    ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
    if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
        // we have no matching number just continue
    }

    // see how many we have
    $i = count($matches['browser']);
    if ($i != 1) {
        //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
        //see if version is before or after the name
        if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][1];
        }
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }

    // check if we have a number
    if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

    return array(
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
    );
} 

// now try it
$ua=getBrowser();
$yourbrowser= "Your browser: " . $ua['name'] . " " . $ua['version'] . " on " .$ua['platform'] . " reports: <br >" . $ua['userAgent'];
print_r($yourbrowser);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Many browsers have Mozilla/5.0 or something at the beginning of their user agents. So if you are going to detect browsers like that, there could be problem. You can however use this `get_browser()` function to do that for you. It is quite accurate and you won't have to bother yourself with so many regexes (which you will also need to keep updating )

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

It can be implemented like this:

```
<?php
$browser = get_browser($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], true);
if($browser['browser'] == 'Mozilla'){
    echo 'Mozilla';
}else if($browser['browser'] == 'Chrome'){
    echo 'Chrome';
}
?>
```

Comment: But is there a way using my way?

Comment: @F4LLCON yes but why would you want to use your way after reading this .

Comment: Because the code I use works after tweaking it for almost 6 hours, so I don't want to change the script for only chrome. Could you tell me how to implement chrome in the script?

Comment: Hmmm...I had face similar problem, when I needed to detect mobile browsers and desktop browsers. It is quite tricky to keep track of great many different user agents. So I resorted to this approach. Your approach will work, but you will have to keep on updating your regex to detect browsers. `get_browser` can detect many different browsers with a lot of other details. Thus it will also help reduce your code

Comment: hmmm, what you could do is that inside the block for `mozilla` you can put additional checks for words as `webkit` or `chrome` in UA string using strpos() or similar implementation. So that way you will be able to separate real mozilla from webkit browsers. But this is still a very patchy approach

Comment: @F4LLCON I have deleted code I worked on for months. Why is it a problem? Accept your losses and use it as a learning experience.

Comment: I agree with Esailija. I worked on friendly frames implementation to load ad banners asynchronously for 2 weeks. A lot of testing and hard work, cross browser testing. Then I came to know about a very sturdy library that does it in one line. I had to leave my lovely 300 lines of javascript code :(  .... but hey it really paid off at the end

Comment: changing 300 lines by 1 line, I would do that :) but changing 300 lines by 300 lines is out of range. I have to change few scripts and pages for one thing. And I tested the getBrowser, doesn't work

Comment: See edited answer. That's all that you have to do. And sometimes it is not about number of lines, but accuracy also matters. This function has been tested and is being used by many devs. So it has be pretty solid. Btw are you sure when you say get_browser doesn't work. And function name is in not in camel case like getBrowser ;)

Comment: And I don't think this one will increase your lines of code...cheers

Comment: @Shades88 That code you gave me gives `Array` instead of anything else. So I searched on the php manual function.get-browser.php and found this code that works. Thanks anyways